# Call Automation in iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ui-automation

Is it possible to simulate call procedure in an **iOS App** using any script.

Launch  Phone App
Pres Key Pad
Dial Numbers
Press End call

Gone through the following link.

[IPhone Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018001/iphone-automation)

I am looking for commands similar to adb commands.

Like the following command

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL tel:123456789
```

I tried using the following code to dial the call from the App

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://123456789"]];
```

Now I get different view, Is it possible to access the elements in this view from Javascript ? I would like to end the call after 5 seconds by simulating the End button
touch using some script. Is it feasible ?

Is there any API to accept and reject calls within the App?

I searched for this earlier but did not find any API.
I want to try it as an internal app and I don't want to submit in the AppStore and I am looking for non jail broken devices.

Comment: If you just want it for testing purposes, try looking into the private APIs https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no API to interact with any of the phone features on an iPhone, other than openURL:

Comment: Although there is a distinct difference in the behavior of tel://1234567890 and telprompt://1234567890 as far as placing calls.  telprompt is not officially part of Apple docs though, so no guarantees.  Would definitely want to check if the url can be opened (canOpenURL) before using telprompt.